# How to access a property from an object using a variable name?

Tags: powershell, object, powershell-5.0

This works:

```
$psISE.Options.DebugBackgroundColor = '#FFC86400'
```

This doesn't:

```
$attribute = 'DebugBackgroundColor' 
($psISE.Options)[$attribute] = '#FFC86400'
```

> ERROR: Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions

I want to set option attributes in a `foreach` loop using the `$attribute` variable.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use double quotes after the dot:

```
$attribute = 'DebugBackgroundColor'
$psISE.Options."$attribute"
```

Comment: No need in double quotes. This work just fine: `$psISE.Options.$attribute`.